# How to convert local time array to UTC array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have tried to combine `timezonefinder` and `pytz` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pytz import timezone
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

tf = TimezoneFinder()

def get_utc(local_time, lat, lon):
    """
    returns a location's time zone offset from UTC in minutes.
    """
    tz_target = timezone(tf.certain_timezone_at(lng=lon, lat=lat))
    utc_time = tz_target.localize(pd.to_datetime(local_time))
    return utc_time.utcnow()

# lon and lat of grid
lon = np.arange(-180, 180, 0.625)
lat = np.arange(-90, 90.5, 0.5)

local_time = np.full((len(lat), len(lon)), np.datetime64('2019-08-11 14:00'))
utc_time = np.full((len(lat), len(lon)), None)

for i in range(len(lat)):
    for j in range(len(lon)):
        utc_time[i, j] = get_utc(local_time[i, j], lat[i], lon[j])
```

However, I got error as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownTimeZoneError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/xin/Documents/github/erc-uptrop/analysis/merra2_gmi.ipynb Cell 5 in <cell line: 8>()
      8 for i in range(len(lat)):
      9     for j in range(len(lon)):
---> 10         utc_time[i, j] = get_utc(local_time[i, j], lat[i], lon[j])

/Users/xin/Documents/github/erc-uptrop/analysis/merra2_gmi.ipynb Cell 5 in get_utc(local_time, lat, lon)
      8 def get_utc(local_time, lat, lon):
      9     """
     10     returns a location's time zone offset from UTC in minutes.
     11     """
---> 12     tz_target = timezone(tf.certain_timezone_at(lng=lon, lat=lat))
     13     utc_time = tz_target.localize(pd.to_datetime(local_time))
     14     return utc_time.utcnow()

File ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/arctic/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py:168, in timezone(zone)
    131 r''' Return a datetime.tzinfo implementation for the given timezone
    132 
    133 >>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   (...)
    165 
    166 '''
    167 if zone is None:
--> 168     raise UnknownTimeZoneError(None)
    170 if zone.upper() == 'UTC':
    171     return utc

UnknownTimeZoneError: None
```

Is it possible to convert data using other methods?

Comment: `certain_timezone_at` is not guaranteed to return a time zone; you don't catch that case in your code (as the error tells you)

Comment: some general remarks: [pytz is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/), use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html); and are you sure [utcnow does what you think it does](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html)? Also, if you're working with time zones, numpy datetime64 might not be the most convenient choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code, that handles the timezone not found problem. In that case, `np.datetime64("NaT")` is returned, which allows you to keep the dtype of the result as `np.datetime64`.

I also took the freedom to replace `pytz` and use native Python datetime instead of `pandas`.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

import numpy as np
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

tf = TimezoneFinder()

def get_utc(local_time, lat, lon):
    tz_target = tf.certain_timezone_at(lng=lon, lat=lat)
    if not tz_target:
        # handle "time zone not found" appropriately
        return np.datetime64("NaT")
    # datetime.datetime detour to handle time zone conversion
    local_time = local_time.astype(datetime).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(tz_target))
    utc_time = local_time.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC"))
    # numpy complains when given aware datetime, so we strip the tzinfo:
    return np.datetime64(utc_time.replace(tzinfo=None))


# lon and lat of grid
lon = np.arange(-180, 180, 10)
lat = np.arange(-90, 90.5, 10)

local_time = np.full((len(lat), len(lon)), np.datetime64('2019-08-11 14:00'))
utc_time = np.full((len(lat), len(lon)), None)

for i in range(len(lat)):
    for j in range(len(lon)):
        utc_time[i, j] = get_utc(local_time[i, j], lat[i], lon[j])
```